# CONSOLE_FONT_INFOEX not defined in Windows C++

Tags: c++, winapi, fonts

I'm trying to change the size of the font in a C++ console program. This code worked before in the past, but now I'm getting an error:

> 'CONSOLE_FONT_INFOEX' was not declared in this scope

Here is my code:

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main() {
    CONSOLE_FONT_INFOEX font;
    font.cbSize = sizeof(font);
    font.nFont = 0;
    font.dwFontSize.X = 8;
    font.dwFontSize.Y = 8;
    SetCurrentConsoleFontEx(GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE), FALSE, &font);
    cout << "Hello world";
}
```

Comment: `Minimum supported client Windows Vista [desktop apps only]` Have you selected a proper Windows target?

Comment: Things just don't start to fail without reason. You made something that stopped this from working. What have you done between it working, and now when it's not working? What have you installed on your system? What have you removed?

Comment: There's nothing that I can think of that would have changed. What kind of things are there that could change this?

Comment: @BenLeib You said this was working fine before. Is this code in a new project? Did you compare the config of the two projects for differences? You likely just forgot to tell the compiler that you are targeting Vista+ w/ GDI enabled. If you look in `wincon.h`, you will see that both struct and function declarations are wrapped inside of `#ifndef NOGDI`, and the function declaration is also wrapped in `#if(_WIN32_WINNT >= 0x0500)`

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't reproduce the issue.

The `CONSOLE_FONT_INFOEX` has been in the Windows SDK since Vista.

First you need to make sure that you have successfully installed the Windows SDK. And your project's windows sdk version is referencing the SDK installed on your machine.

I suggest you could also try to add `#include <consoleapi3.h>` to your source file.

Comment: How do I make my project reference the sdk? I'm using notepad++, and compiling on the command line.

Comment: @BenLeib I've compiled it by developer command line. It successfully modifies the font size of the command line. If you have installed the windows software development kit-10.0.22621, uninstall it and reinstall it by the link: https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/downloads/windows-sdk/
   Or you can modified it in visual studio installer: https://i.stack.imgur.com/HnKi1.png

Comment: It works now. I just had to uninstall and reinstall dev c++. Thanks for your help